# How to access enclosing classes variables from an instance of a public nested class of the enclosing class in a nice manner?

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

Consider the following code example in java:

```
    public class Packet {

    protected int offset = 0;
    public int type;

    public Packet() {
        // This is the backward out-constructor. Every sub class must call its superior classes .new () to live!
        offset++; // For type
    }

    int[] compile(int[] outBuffer) {
        // This is the top-down compilation routine. Every sub class should call its superior compile() in a similar manner, as recursion is only possible this way!
        int dOffset = offset;
        outBuffer[--offset] = this.type;
        int[] result = outBuffer;
        offset = dOffset;
        return result;
    }

    public class Command {

        public int opCode;
        public int length;

        public Command() {
            // OpCode and length are set by sub-classes!
            type = 0x01;
            offset += 3;
            length = 0; // Init only
        }

        int[] compile(int[] outBuffer) {
            int dOffset = offset;
            offset -= 3;
            outBuffer[offset] = opCode & 0xFF;
            outBuffer[offset + 1] = (opCode >>> 8) & 0xFF;
            outBuffer[offset + 2] = length;
            int[] result = Packet.this.compile(outBuffer);
            offset = dOffset;
            return result;
        }

        public class HWCommand {
            // And so on... 8 more nesting levels in my project
        }

    }

    public Packet(int[] data) {
        // This is the forward in-constructor.
        if (data.length > 0) {
            type = data[offset++];
        }
    }

    public class Event {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I am currently using a strcture like this that has about 9 to 10 levels of this kind of nesting to decode packets of a ridiculously complicated protocol that I have no influence on to my utter regret. It is working fine so far, only is it my task to adapt it to a certain architecture at the moment.

Sometimes, when the computer at the other end of the connection through that protocol is just not ready to receive a new command packet since it is still busy processing the last one because the sheer processing is such pain, it would just reject my packet and notify me with the OpCode and a number of rather irrelevant properties.

The correct way to react would then be to wait for a random time and retry sending that command.

Now what I'd like to have is a way to access for example Packet.Command's OpCode variable when I only have an instance of Packet.Command.HWCommand. ... .SubClass sp; - so I can have an associative HashMap with OpCodes and Comands and just grab the ones that were not confirmed with a success message and re-send them.

I have already considered:

1. Implementing getters and setters (Doesn't seem like a good idea to me)
2. Keeping a reference to the Packet.Command from of which SubClass was instantiated (would work ok, but requires 10k+ lines of code to be changed as those sending routines are in heavy use)
3. Leaking the this$0 ref. through getters (e.g. create a parent() function)
4. Saving the Raw Data of the last packet sent, reparse it to that massive protocol data structure and then re-send it (seems ... *a bit* strange to me)

Which of them is the best way to do it, or is there any better one I am not aware of?

Comment: You have considered "Implementing getters and setters" but it doesn't seem like a good idea to you? Unless you have a very good reason not to, it is.

Comment: Well, the thing is, those'd have to be implemented throughout the all nested classes which is somewhat complicated ... only a few hundred to 1k lines ok code to be changed though